# How to compare a column from a table to a text in a column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my DB

Table1:

```
caseId     name     ApprovalDate     ApprovalSatus
150150     John     2018-01-29       41
150151     Dave     2018-01-02       41
```

Table2:

```
contId     StatusSourceNoKeyId     Status     contractDate
210210     38^|^150150^|^31796794  41         2018-02-01 
210211     38^|^150150^|^31796797  40         2018-01-28
210220     38^|^150151^|^31796720  41         2018-01-03
```

I need to find out date difference between `contractDate` in Table2 and `ApprovalDate` in Table1 when CaseId in Table1 is like

'38^|^caseId^|^31796794' in table2 and Status is '41'.

How can I do such a select?

Thanks,

Comment: have u tried anything so far with Joins ?

Comment: what kind of "date difference" do you mean... do you want to know how many days are between them?

Comment: Do u have 2 status columns in Table2 ?

Comment: @Van Hi, not sth. that can give me a result. And ApprovalStatus in Table1 and Status in table 2 are the same

Comment: @Hello_my_dog_can_code I need then in days or hours. doesn't matter because it can be deifined in datediff(), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL-Server you have the [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) Function

Quick Example:

```
select 
DATEDIF(day, b.contractDate, a.ApprovalDate) as difference, * 
from Table1 a
left join 
Table2 b on b.StatusSourceNoKeyId like '%^'+ a.caseId +'^%' 
and a.ApprovalStatus = b.Status
```

this should work, i haven't tested it though.

Comment: Thanks. But your solution is still running after 18 minuts! I ran it in a real database which is quite heavy but it shouldn't take this long!

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, I have changed the query to a Common Table Expression. You can use your actual tables for this.

```
;WITH CTE1
AS
(
SELECT '150150'  caseId, 'John' Name, '2018-01-29' ApprovalDate,     41 'ApprovalSatus' UNION
SELECT '150151'    ,'Dave'    ,'2018-01-02'     , 41
)
, CTE2
AS
(

SELECT 210210 contId,    '38^|^150150^|^31796794' StatusSourceNoKeyId,    41 Status,      '2018-02-01' contractDate UNION
SELECT 210211    ,'38^|^150150^|^31796797',    40       ,'2018-01-28' UNION
SELECT 210211    ,'38^|^150152^|^31796797',    40       ,'2018-01-28' UNION
SELECT 210220    ,'38^|^150151^|^31796720',    41       ,'2018-01-03'
)
SELECT CTE1.caseId, DATEDIFF(DD, cte1.ApprovalDate, cte2.contractDate) DatDiff FROM CTE1 INNER JOIN CTE2 ON
CTE2.StatusSourceNoKeyId LIKE '%^'+CTE1.caseId+'^%' 
WHERE CTE2.Status = '41'
```

In your case the query could be like

```
SELECT Tablle1.caseId, DATEDIFF(DD, Tablle1.ApprovalDate, Tablle2.contractDate) DatDiff FROM Tablle1 INNER JOIN Tablle2 ON
Tablle2.StatusSourceNoKeyId LIKE '%^'+Tablle1.caseId+'^%' 
WHERE Tablle2.Status = '41'
```